# Android Screen Orientation: Landscape Back to Portrait

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I have designed an activity that its orientation is landscape. Also I have designed another that its orientation is portrait. When I run in my phone, there are some problems comes to when the landscape activity back to the portrait activity. 
Some of the layout disappear, such as below

original:

[image: Original]

after 
[image: after]

can anyone help me to solve this problem?Thank you so much!

```
<activity android:name="TestingActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation" > </activity> 
<activity android:name="Main"> 
  <intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category> 
  </intent-filter> 
</activity> 
<activity android:name=".TestingActivity2" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

Comment: post your layout code. Not manifest file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in layout-portrait xml file. You can fix it by redesigning it. Please post your code.