# Phonegap/HTML5 and Android screen resize issue on rotate from landscape to portrait

Tags: android, html, cordova, rotation, portrait

I'm experiencing an odd problem with an android phonegap application right now when the user rotates from landscape to portrait, but not the other way around.

When the screen is rotated from landscape to portait, the height of the content viewport seems to remain at the previous height - however the width of the viewport resizes correctly. The following images try to show this a little clearer:

[image: Landscape view...] rotates to
[image: ... and then portrait view]

I saw this question: [Android Screen Orientation: Landscape Back to Portrait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678197/android-screen-orientation-landscape-back-to-portrait)
...but while the accepted answer may true, I'm not entirely sure what is being asked for there.

I only have a layout/main.xml that carries the default configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have also tried putting in some orientation detection scripting to see if that helps - I've tried:

```
    var viewPortHeight = $(window).height();
alert (viewPortHeight+" x "+$(window).width());
var headerHeight = $('div[data-role="header"]').height();
var footerHeight = 0;
var contentHeight = viewPortHeight - headerHeight - footerHeight;

// Set all pages with class="page-content" to be at least contentHeight
$('div[class="page-content"]').css({'min-height': contentHeight + 'px'});
```

and also

```
                var devInfo = new DeviceInformation();
            devInfo.setOrientation(0);
            time_column_count = Math.floor(viewport.height / 270);
            devInfo.setResolution({
                height  : $(window).width(),
                width : $(window).height()
            });
```

but - no dice. Any ideas here?

**UPDATE**

This only seems to be a problem on ICS devices - and there is actually a scrolling problem in landscape mode on devices that are experiencing this issue. JQM Scroll is being used to enable scrolling on the different divs.

Comment: Have you ever try add android:layout_weight="1" to root view? Well seems it's layout issue..

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything... and it's really odd that it only occurs in ICS...

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue with phonegap a while back. The code below should hopefully help you solve this issue.

1 - Make sure that the phonegap.js file is being called within the head of the html file

2 - Add the following meta tag within the head of the html page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

3 - Add an event listener in the onDeviceReady()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onDeviceReady() 
{
    document.addEventListener("orientationChanged", updateOrientation);
}
</script>
```

4 - If you want to add specific changes to differnet orientations, possibly different images, use a similar switch statement

```
function updateOrientation()
{
    var e = window.orientation;
    switch(e)
    {  
        case 0:
            // PORTRAIT
        break;

        case -90:
            // LANDSCAPE
        break;

        case 90:
            // LANDSCAPE
        break;

        default:
            //PORTRAIT
        break;
    }        
}
```

5 - Add the following style after your closing javascript tag

```
<style>
    [data-role=page]{height: 100% !important; position:relative !important; top:0 !important;}
</style>
```

Please try the above and let me know if it work, if not there are a few other approaches you could take.

Thanks,
L & L Partners

Comment: Thanks for this - but unfortunately it did not work. I have the following meta tag: '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>' and I inserted the style snippet you provided immediately after my script tags, but it made no difference...

Answer (score 1):

Go to manifest file:

inside the activity add the below attributes:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

Comment: I'll check this suggestion out and let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with the earlier comment on using viewport metatag.  Though I would add that you should also specify your intended pixel density for your layout.

One thing I have found to be invaluable in in laying out portait vs. lanscape on mobile devices is using CSS media queries.  These will allow you to change the CSS styling of of screen elements in landscape and portrait modes without having to rely on javascript at all.
This also allow better control in laying out thing for smartphone vs. tablet as well.

Comment: I use media queries as well - all my CSS files support portrait/landscape media queries - using structures like: '@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) and (orientation: portrait)' to detect portrait pads - but this has not made any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with Intel xdk app framework with cordova build in.
To resolve the problem all i did was to do a new project, copy everything i had in the previous one and rebuild cordova in it. Altough this time, i didn't add the plugins trough the interface but only copied the config files that was in my previous project. Strangely enough it worked and now the viewport adjusts just fine. So my guess is its probably a problems with the version or something in the configs is wrong.

Hope that helped in some way.

P.S sorry for the poor english

**UPDATE**
It seemed the problem persisted when i've built the application. To resolve the problem (for now as it seems to be the only solution ) is to do this.

```js
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', doOnOrientationChange);
function doOnOrientationChange()
  {
    switch(window.orientation) 
    {  
      case -90:
      case 90:
                setTimeout(function(){
                var ScreenHeight = screen.height;
                document.body.style.height = '100%';
                window.innerHeight = ScreenHeight - (FOOTER HEADER);},100);
        break; 
      default:
            var ScreenHeight = screen.height;
            document.body.style.height = "100%";
            window.innerHeight = ScreenHeight - (FOOTER HEADER);
        break; 
    }
  }
```

It works 99% of the time(sometimes it doesn't adjust properly but it doesn't happen often) and there is a bit of laging in the interface for a few frames. If you wonder why there is timeout in the landscape its because for some reason, it gets override by....something. I don't know why  cordova does this but, for the time being, its the only way i found to resolve this bug.

Hope it helps :-D